# Hibernate many to many бесконечно вложенный json

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Есть три таблицы `user`, `group`, `user2group`. Связь много ко многим.

Если прописать мапинг только в классе `User`, то контроллер выдает json который и нужен.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "user2group", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "group_id") })
private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>();
```

Но если мапим связанные данные в классе `Group`, то при попытке получить список групп с привязанными к ним клиентами, контроллер начинает выдавать json, но при этом бесконечно проваливается в связанные сущности.

Мапинг для класса `Group` сейчас у меня следующий:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups")
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
```

Записи я получаю следующим образом

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM User");
List<User> users = query.list();
```

Также, на случай если это важно. По началу при обращении к соответствующему урлу, вылетало исключение, которое починилось установкой следующего нагугленного свойства при инициализации бина `LocalSessionFactory`:

```
properties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans",  true);
```

**Вопрос**. Чтобы получать json единой вложенности, нужны какие-то особенные настройки хибернейта? Или прописывать особый маппинг?

В ходе гугления вопроса мне начало казаться, что особо ни у кого не возникает подобной сложности, может тут подход нужен иной?

**Задача**
Возможность получить всех юзеров, где к каждому юзеру будет прикреплен список групп, в которых он числится.
Пример:

```
[
  {id:1, name:"user1", groups:[{id:1, title:"group1"}, {id:5, title:"group5"}]},
  {id:2, name:"user2", groups:[]},
  {id:3, name:"user3", groups:[{id:3, title:"group3"}]},
]
```

Возможность получить все группы, где к каждой группе будет прикреплен список юзеров, которые числятся в этой группе
Пример:

```
[
  {id:1, title:"group1", users:[{id:1, name:"user1"}, {id:5, name:"user5"}]},
  {id:2, title:"group2", users:[]},
  {id:3, title:"group3", users:[{id:3, name:"user3"}]},
]
```

Comment: можно как-то по другому сформулировать вопрос и объяснить, что значит json единой вложенности? 
и еще приведите пример select'a из базы. что вы получаете?
вы хотите получить только юзеров, которые входят в одну определенную группу?

Comment: Таких сложногстей обычно не возникает, поскольку сущности Hibernate принято выделять в отдельный слой, а наружу отдавать DTO. Если в проекте вы используете Jackson в качестве JSON провейдера, используйте аннотации `@JsonManagedReference` и `@JsonBackReference` на соот. полях сущностей. [Примерно таким образом](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18288939/5694145)

Comment: @enzo Я попробовал вариант по вашей ссылке, а также погуглил примеры с этими аннотациями. В json'е присутствуют значения свойства помеченного `@JsonManagedReference`, а свойство помеченное `@JsonBackReference` отсутствует в json'е таблицы `group`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не очень хорошая практика - отдавать ваши ORM-сущности непосредственно наружу.

Во-первых, вы смешиваете разные задачи в одном классе.

Во-вторых, вы отдаете наружу все его состояние, которое, возможно, не стоит отдавать.

В третьих, когда-нибудь вам потребуется отдавать для разных задач разный набор полей.

Обычно, эта проблема решается паттерном DTO ([Data Transfer Object](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTO)).

Вы просто создаете классы `UserDto` и `GroupDto`, которые содержат только необходимые поля, геттеры-сеттеры, конструктор по-умолчанию и JSON-аннотации. При отдаче наружу в слое представления (контроллере) перекладываете поля из ORM-объектов в DTO-объекты. Можно это делать как вручную (завести static-метод в DTO), так и использовать какой-нибудь маппер вроде Dozer.

Для получения групп с вложенными в нее пользователями, нужно завести отдельную DTO, например, как `GroupWithUsersDto` в примере ниже.

---

```
public class GroupDto {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private Long id;
  @JsonProperty("title")
  private String title;

  // сеттеры-геттеры

  public static GroupDto fromModel(Group group) {
    GroupDto dto = new GroupDto();
    dto.setId(group.getId());
    dto.setTitle(group.getTitle());
    return dto;
}


public class UserDto {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private Long id;
  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name;

  // сеттеры-геттеры

  public static UserWithGroupsDto fromModel(User user) {
    UserWithGroupsDto dto = new UserWithGroupsDto();
    dto.setId(user.getId());
    dto.setName(user.getName());
    return dto;
  }
}
```

Для выдачи пользователей с их группами:

```
public class UserWithGroupsDto {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private Long id;
  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name;
  @JsonProperty("groups")
  private List<GroupDto> groups;

  // сеттеры-геттеры

  public static UserWithGroupsDto fromModel(User user) {
    UserWithGroupsDto dto = new UserWithGroupsDto();
    dto.setId(user.getId());
    dto.setName(user.getName());
    List<GroupDto> groupDtos = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Group group : user.getGroups()) {
      groupDtos.add(GroupDto.fromModel(group));
    }
    dto.setGroups(groupDtos);

    return dto;
  }
}
```

---

Для выдачи групп с пользователями:

```
public class GroupWithUsersDto{
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private Long id;
  @JsonProperty("title")
  private String title;
  @JsonProperty("users")
  private List<UserShortDto>


  // сеттеры-геттеры

  public static GroupWithUsersDto fromModel(Group group) {
    GroupWithUsersDto dto = new GroupWithUsersDto();
    dto.setId(group.getId());
    dto.setTitle(group.getTitle());
    List<UserDto> usersDtos = new ArrayList<>();

    for (User user : group.getUsers()) {
      usersDtos.add(UserDto.fromModel(user));
    }
    dto.setUsers(usersDtos);
    return dto;
}
```

Comment: ну да. Только я бы отказался от статик методов.

Comment: код конвертации должен где-то лежать.

Comment: Хотя да, я почему-то делал отдельный класс и конвертация всех сущностей была в нем. Наверно не очень хороший подход. Класс будет сильно увеличиваться с ростом сущностей

Comment: Статический factory-метод это очень распространенный подход. DTO знает о моделях, модели не знают о DTO.

Comment: В качестве транформера м/у сущностями удобно использовать [orika](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/mappings-via-classmapbuilder.html). Если названия полей классов совпадают, как чаще всего и бывает, кода вообще минимум - делается FactoryBean и инжектится в нужные контроллеры..

Comment: а зачем отдельную DTO  UserWithGroupsDto можно же у юзера сделать 
      private List<GroupDto> groups;
и два конструктора с группами и без

Answer (score 4):

Можно повесить в классе Group на поле

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups")
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
```

аннотацию `@JsonIgnore`

Или использовать слой DTO

```
package my.company.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    @Column(name="time_registration")
    private Date timeRegistration;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_to_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Album> albums;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_to_dialogs",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dialog_id"))
    private List<Dialog> dialogs;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Message> messages;
    @OneToOne
    private Avatar avatar;

    public User() {
    }


public User(String name, String surname, String password, String email, Date timeRegistration, Set<Role> roles) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.timeRegistration = timeRegistration;
    this.roles = roles;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public List<Album> getAlbums() {
    return albums;
}

public void setAlbums(List<Album> albums) {
    this.albums = albums;
}

public Date getTimeRegistration() {
    return timeRegistration;
}

public void setTimeRegistration(Date timeRegistration) {
    this.timeRegistration = timeRegistration;
}

public List<Dialog> getDialogs() {
    return dialogs;
}

public void setDialogs(List<Dialog> dialogs) {
    this.dialogs = dialogs;
}

public List<Message> getMessages() {
    return messages;
}

public void setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public Avatar getAvatar() {
    return avatar;
}

public void setAvatar(Avatar avatar) {
    this.avatar = avatar;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return id + " " + name + " " + email;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    User user = (User) o;

    return id == user.id;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
}


}
```

package my.company.DTO;

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class UserDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    @JsonProperty("albums")
    private List<AlbumDTO> albumDTOs;
    private Date timeRegistration;
    private Long avatarId;

    public UserDTO(Long id, String name, String surname, String email, Date timeRegistration, Long avatarId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.email = email;
        this.timeRegistration = timeRegistration;
        this.avatarId = avatarId;
    }

    public UserDTO(Long id, String name, String surname, String email, List<AlbumDTO> albumDTOs, Date timeRegistration) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.email = email;
        this.albumDTOs = albumDTOs;
        this.timeRegistration = timeRegistration;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<AlbumDTO> getAlbumDTOs() {
        return albumDTOs;
    }

    public void setAlbumDTOs(List<AlbumDTO> albumDTOs) {
        this.albumDTOs = albumDTOs;
    }

    public Date getTimeRegistration() {
        return timeRegistration;
    }

    public void setTimeRegistration(Date timeRegistration) {
        this.timeRegistration = timeRegistration;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public Long getAvatarId() {
        return avatarId;
    }

    public void setAvatarId(Long avatarId) {
        this.avatarId = avatarId;
    }
}
```

Comment: но тогда ведь это свойство будет отсутствовать в json выдаче. Мне нужна возможность получить список всех групп, и чтобы к каждой группе был прикреплен список юзеров, которые относятся к ней. Такая же задача с юзерами

Comment: нет. вы хотите вывести юзера и все его группы? берется юзер, берутся все его группы, группы начинают преобразовываться тож в json. у группы есть опять ваш юзер, юзер начинает в json и опять группы. Зацикливание. Либо игнорироать, либо создавать отдельные сущности например UserDTO и GroupDTO и формировать их при отдаче клиенту

Comment: А можно вас попросить ссылку с примером на подобную реализацию?

Comment: реализацию чего именно?

Comment: Вы упоминули примеры сущностей UserDTO и GroupDTO, я так понимаю это какой-то дополнительный слой

Comment: Да , это доп слой. Вы будете формировать сущности с теми полями которые вы хотите. Делаете например вспомогательный класс EntityConverter и у него методы например  `public UserDTO userToDTO(User user) { }` где из входящего User собираете вашего UserDTO с теми полями что вам надо

Comment: @MrGarison А как правильно вернуть ответ на страницу?? По аналогии с комментариями сделала прослойку DTo  В Controller ``@RequestMapping(value = "/me",method = GET) @ResponseBody public List<SubjectDto> getAll(){ List<Subject> subjects = subjectService.getAll(); List<SubjectDto> subjectDtos = new ArrayList<>(subjects.size()); subjects.forEach(subject -> subjectDtos.add(convertToDTO(subject))); return subjectDtos;` ``но программа ругается на convertToDTO как будто не понимает, что это за метод